# How to share one LINQ query between two methods?

Tags: c#, linq

is there any way to share one LINQ query between two methods? I have quite long LINQ query that gets search results from database and I need to use this query to get results (some kind of list<>) -first method - and to get its count (int) - second method -. I don't want to copy this query in two separate methods and I can't return custom class object containing search results and  records count (returned by this query). So what I want to do is to get LINQ query definition(or something like this?) but no the results set that I can use in other methods. Maybe there is another good way to do that. thanks for yout help ;)

the code look like this:

```
public ??? GetSearchResultsQuery(SearchRequest search_request)
{
    var queryGetSearchResults = ....
    return queryGetSearchResults;
} 

public int GetSearchResultsCount(SearchRequest search_request)
{
    return GetSearchResultsQuery(search_request).Count();
}

public List<SearchResults> GetSearchResults(SearchRequest search_request)
{
return GetSearchResultsQuery(search_request).Skip(search_request.startRowIndex).Take(search_request.maximumRows).ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: You would want to return IQueryable here

Comment: Just a note, Visual Studio gives IntelliSense on the type of `var` in most occasions when you hover the mouse over it.

Answer (score 4):

```
public IQueryable<SearchedForType> GetSearchResultsQuery(SearchRequest search_request)
{
    var queryGetSearchResults = context.SearchedForTypes.Where(x => x == search_request.X);
    ... build up your search query ...
    return queryGetSearchResults;
}
```